# What is the nature of the constraint acting on a projectile thrown at some angle with the horizontal surface?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, projectile

Suppose a projectile is thrown at some angle with the horizontal surface. It is known that the trajectory of the projectile will be a parabola in the vertical plane, assuming there is no air resistance. My question is - what is the nature of the constraint acting on the projectile? Is it holonomic or non-holonomic or something else?

Comment: What constraint are you referring to?  Do you mean the constraint that the projectile not sink down into the Earth when it lands?

Comment: No, I mean that when the projectile is in the air, it moves in the vertical plane only. So, it's constrained to move in that plane. Is this constraint holonomic, non-holonomic or something else? Or have I gone wrong somewhere conceptually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No, I mean that when the projectile is in the air, it moves in the vertical plane only. So, it's constrained to move in that plane.

No it isn't.  If you have a 3D coordinate system $(x,y,z)$ with $z$ being the vertical direction, then you can arrange for it to travel in the $(x,z)$ plane by giving it an initial velocity with no $y$-component, but you can arrange for it travel in the $(y,z)$-plane by giving it an initial velocity with no $x$-component.  There is no constraint forcing the particle to travel in one particular plane.

That being said, once the projectile is fired it always stays in the same vertical plane because there are no forces in the $x$- or $y$-directions.  But that's not the same as it being constrained to move only in one particular plane.

Similarly, a free particle in 3D space moves with constant velocity, so it will trace out a line in space.  But it is not *constrained* to move along that line; different initial conditions will yield a trajectory which is along a different line.

Comment: Ok. That clears things up. What about the nature of the constraint that the projectile not sink into the earth when it lands? Will that be non-holonomic? Or does it depend on how I define the location of the ground level with respect to my coordinate frame?

Comment: @AnubhabBiswas That is the constraint that $z \geq 0$.  Since this is not of the form $f(x,y,z)=0$, it is a non-holonomic constraint.